# Continuous functions specific proof

Tags: calculus, functions

**Prove:** If $f : [0, 1]\to [0, 1]$  is continuous and $f(0) = f(1)$, then there
exists a point $0 \le x\le  \frac{1}{2}$ such that $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{2})$

**Hint:** Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(x+\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: What's $g(0) + g(1/2)$? What can you conclude?

Comment: You seem to have a perfectly good hint there. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(x)=f(x)-f\left(x+\frac12\right)$$
Put $x=0$,
$$g(0)=f(0)-f\left(\frac12\right)$$
Put $x=\frac12$,
$$g\left(\frac12\right)=f\left(\frac12\right)-f(1)$$
Since $f(0)=f(1)$, we have,
$$g\left(\frac12\right)=f\left(\frac12\right)-f(0)=-g(0)$$

By the intermediate value theorem, which can be applied due to the continuity of $f$ and hence $g$, there exists an $x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$ such that $g(x)=0$, which gives
$$f(x)=f\left(x+\frac12\right)$$